# Read multiple csv files and store content as list referenced by different names

Tags: python, function, variables

So I have code that basically does this:

```
def setup_list(file_name):
    for item in csv file:
        list = []
        list.append(item)
```

However, I want to be able to assign list a different name each time the function is run. For example `list_one`, `list_two` etc. How can I do this?

From comment:

The end goal is too have the contents of several csv files stored in a few lists with different names. The files contain birds, dates and location in the same file.

I have several files as users may have several bird lists they wish to make (one for birds seen in their county/state, another file for birds seen all over the world etc.)

Comment: What is the end goal of this approach? Seeing the full function in some sort of pseudocode might help tailor responses to more accurately reflect what you are looking for

Comment: You might want a dictionary. Variable names should be fixed in code, not themselves variable.

Comment: You want a list of lists. Renaming variables (not practical) not a good idea anyway.

Comment: could you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some expected output for the question? You should consider using a dictionary for the lists.

Comment: NOTE: you shouldn't used Python built-ins as variable names (i.e. don't use `list` as a variable name)

Comment: why is he getting down voted? he's just looking for possible answers.

Comment: @minboost Thanks for the tip - my actually variables name are birds, dates and locations so I should be fine. That code is simplified.

Comment: @Nidhin_toms Welcome to the ultra strict world of stackoverflow

Comment: I'd agree that either a `list` of `list`s or `dictionary` would be sufficient here. If you are using this function to *update* an existing data structure, local variable names will probably not persist, so the names are relatively immaterial here

Comment: @PatrickArtner What advantage would pseudo code have in this context, I have explained it as simply as possible.

Comment: @KingBalloonion It's simple, yes, but not complete. The function you posted doesn't return anything, and there's no context, so it's hard to tell what you want it to do. For example I'm thinking the best solution is to turn `setup_list` into a generator, and name its output in the calling scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read multiple files and its content into lists:

**Create data:**

```
with open("birds1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(f"""
Bird,Date,Location
Amsel,1.1.2018,Amerika
Drossel,2.1.2018,Alaska
Fink,3.1.2018,Pacific
""")

with open("birds2.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(f"""
Bird,Date,Location
Eagle,1.1.2018,Afrika
Milan,2.1.2018,Eurasia
AngryBird,3.1.2018,Rainbow Meadow
""")
```

**Load data:**

```
import csv

def load_into_dict(d,filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        name = filename.split(".")[0] 
        d[name] = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row:
                d[name].append(row)

data = {}
for n in ["birds1.txt","birds2.txt"]:
    load_into_dict(data,n)
```

**Usage of loaded data:**

```
print(data)
print(data["birds1"][1])
```

***Output:***

```
{'birds1': [['Bird', 'Date', 'Location'],      ['Amsel', '1.1.2018', 'Amerika'], 
            ['Drossel', '2.1.2018', 'Alaska'], ['Fink', '3.1.2018', 'Pacific']], 
 'birds2': [['Bird', 'Date', 'Location'],      ['Eagle', '1.1.2018', 'Afrika'], 
            ['Milan', '2.1.2018', 'Eurasia'],  ['AngryBird', '3.1.2018', 'Rainbow Meadow']]}

['Amsel', '1.1.2018', 'Amerika']
```

Documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I think you misunderstood my question, birds, dates and location are in the same file. I have several files as users may have several bird lists they wish to make (one for birds seen in their county/state, another file for birds seen all over the world etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer!

Comment: Sorry to bring up this post again but I am now implementing this code. However, if the user has many lists (several hundred are possible), I would only like to load them as the user selects them. For example, if the user selected to edit bird1 to start  and then decided to edit bird5 later, could bird5 be added to the dictionary after bird 1 has or do they have to be added all at once? Also, I am planning of adding the feature of searching by bird name, date or location, would this also be possible?

Comment: You can not have the cake and eat it too - if you want to search for stuff you either need the data in memory or you need to open one file after the other to see if a bird is in it - if you have several hundrets of files, why not transfer the data into a real database? dictionaries are only good to when you know the key - you would need 3 dicts to enable "fast" access to bird: [list of when and where and by whom seen], date: [ list of birds seen at that by, by whom and where] and location: [list of birsd by whom and whenseen] .... Tryit out and ask a new question if you get into troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try that out.

Comment: Am I missing something or should data[name].append(row) be d[name].append(row) instead? Edit - I could of sworn it worked though

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary for the lists, with your desired name as the key and the list as the value

```
dictOfLists = {}

def setup_list(file_name, list_name):
    l = []
    for item in csv file:
        l.append(item)
    dictOfLists.update({list_name : l})
```

It's generally not practical or advisable to rename variables and should not be done in most cases.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed code and moved the list declaration out of the loop

Comment: @BillWang thanks for this, dictionaries look like a good approach